# can i set up a google sheet to receive data from an external webhook/PUSH API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, webhooks

i'm keen to understand if i can use a google sheet / script to receive incoming data from an external (3rd party / non google) webhook.

the webhook requirements:

- a defined / expected method from `POST` (my preferred), `PUT`, `PATCH`
- an endpoint to post to which, if this is possible, i assume would be something like `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[sheet_id]/[service_name]` or even `https://script.google.com/d/[project_id]/[service_name]` where ScriptApp can perform handling of the data
- method of authentication; the current options available from the sending system are "none" or "oauth"
- incoming content; the body is a simple `{ "id": integer }`

**oauth** inputs include `authentication_url`, `azure_subscription_key`, `app_key`, `app_secret`, `resource_id`.

hopefully this is enough information to determine if this is possible. if not then please comment with questions and i'll do my best to answer them. thanks in advance :)

Comment: Although I'm not sure about the detail information of the webhook, when you want to make the webhook directly request to Sheets API, the authorization for retrieving the access token from the refresh token and/or service account. If your webhook can do this, you can achieve it. If your webhook cannot do this, how about using Web Apps and Google Apps Script as an API? When Web Apps is used, you can select freely the authorization method and customize by the script. By this, most webhooks can be achieved this. If these were not useful for your goal, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike thanks for the quick response. i'm not familiar with Webb Apps yet but it looks like i've got some reading to do :)

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer**: Yes, for the most part.

Explanation -

1. > ...receive incoming data from an **external** (3rd party / non google) webhook.

Google Apps Script (GAS) provides a format called as [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) where, you write a script to handle incoming requests and "deploy" the Apps Script itself as a web app. In doing so, GAS provides you with it's own endpoint.

*Adding this as a point of clarification where the endpoint/URL would not be that of a 3rd party, but that of GAS itself, which will need to be used in a 3rd party's application where they require you to provide an endpoint :)*

2. You only have `GET` & `POST` requests (as of now) that can be handled by Apps Script's Web App and not the others that you've stated.
3. The non-dev, prod-ready link would look something like this - `https://script.google.com/macros/s/Unique-Script-ID-Goes-Here/exec`
4. The available auth/permission settings are described [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app).
5. The [request parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters) also describes the format of data that can be processed by the Web App.

Hope this helps but please feel free to ask for any clarifications too, as required.

Comment: thanks for the quick and concise response. i'm not familiar with GAS Web Apps so will try and get my head around the links you posted. also thanks for the offer for further clarification, no doubt i'll take you up on it once i've done a bit of reading and POCing.

Comment: @mitch-NZ - sure thing :) If you need any simple scripts to start-off, do let know. Its super easy to create and execute.

Comment: Hello, I also want to push a status to my google sheet, it would be nice to have a more complete example on how to as this is the top result on SO.